# Ruby - editing gem source code has no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm debugging the nested_set gem which is under `C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\nested_set-1.6.4\lib\nested_set`

I make changes to files in there, but it seems to have no effect when I refresh the page. I deleted the cache file in `C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\cache` to no effect.

Is there some sort of caching I should know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is rails you need to restart your server

Comment: @waitinforatrian in Rails3 just comment it out in your Gemfile and it will disable.  With this version you need to run bundle update && rails server to get it to load and disable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `gem env` from the command line to check that's what's being used?